# pods connectivity chatbotexternal and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, memcached, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

`1. pods were getting into evicted state. because of the less resource.
2. we added new worker nodes which resolves the pods evicted issues.
3. after that we are facing connectivity between two pods i.e chatbotexternal and mongodb.below is the logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.